# run a query saved in a row value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The following select statement gives me three cols and one row.
QueryA

```
SELECT
     -- some calculations and manipulations
     x, y, queryB
     .....
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = UPPER($sch_name)
  AND TABLE_NAME = UPPER($tab_name);
```

One of the returned columns has a query stored. Output

```
x,   y,       queryB
aa   bb       select * from stg.new
```

How can I extend the QueryA such that I select and run the query B and the final output returned is that of queryB not queryA?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of reading from one table to get the SQL, executing the SQL on a different table, and then returning the result of that second statement:

```
create or replace transient table T1 as
select 'This is the final result.' as THE_RESULT
;

create or replace transient table SQL_TO_RUN as
select 'select * from T1' SQL_STATEMENT
;
    
create or replace procedure myprocedure()
  returns table()
  language sql
  execute as caller
  as
  $$
    declare 
         rs resultset default (select SQL_STATEMENT from SQL_TO_RUN);
         c cursor for rs;
         sqlStatement string;
         rsFinal resultset;
    begin
         for rowContents in c do
            sqlStatement := rowContents.SQL_STATEMENT;
         end for;
         rsFinal := (execute immediate :sqlStatement);
         return table(rsFinal);
    end;
  $$
  ;

call myprocedure();
```